# Calling await() on suspend functions do not work correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

```
private val coroutineSupervisor = SupervisorJob()
protected val dispatcherProvider = CoroutineDispatcherProvider()
protected val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(dispatcherProvider.main + coroutineSupervisor)

class CoroutineDispatcherProvider {

    val main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Main

    val background: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.IO
}

viewModelScope.launch {
    ...
    runBlocking {
        async { firstNumber() }.await()
        async { secondNumber() }.await()
        async { test() }.await()
        async { thirdNumber() }.await()
    }
}

suspend fun firstNumber(): Int {
    delay(3_000) // 3 seconds delay
    return 5
}
suspend fun secondNumber(): Int {
    delay(5_000) // 5 seconds delay
    return 8
}
suspend fun thirdNumber(): Int {
    delay(7_000) // 7 seconds delay
    return 10
}

suspend fun test() {
    withContext(dispatcherProvider.background) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Started learning coroutines few days ago and I saw something weird. firstNumber, secondNumber and thirdNumber function run as they should - delay is done and then the next function executes - in the right sequence, but test() does not. It returns value a lot later and runBlocking is already done when that happens. I would like to make sure, that it gets result and then somehow use it in other request. Is it because I'm using some kind of wrong dispatcher there or what?

Comment: can you please add your PortalApiClient class code? want to see whats your return object.

Comment: In test() I call apiClient - get data and add returned data from api to local variable. Test() returns nothing.

Comment: Yes. I understood that but what's the return object of the apiclient. is it Call<>?

Comment: It's a callback. Type is Response<List<Data>>, where Response has "isSuccessful", "error" and result is generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing. What you are expecting when you call test() method through async and await is to wait it till completes.

But As you have a callback flow(apiclient call) inside the test method, it returns immediately before getting response from server and exits the test method. Later Callback lambda is called when the response is ready. By this time run blocking is already done.

So You should do is to convert your callback into Coroutine.
[Codelabs-example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6)

And you can create a list of Deferred objects out of the api call and await on each one.